# 'include' layout comes on top of the Soft Keyboard

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, android-softkeyboard

Please have a look at the following

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sales_inqury_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"    
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SalesInqury" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sales_inq_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/sales_inqury"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_new_sales_inqury_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/add_2" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/sales_inq_title_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="8"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:hint="Search" >
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/alphabet_order"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/sales_inq_title_layout"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/search_2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/open_alphabet" /> 

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alphabet_order" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/sales_inq_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
             >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/presence_audio_online" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/testWord"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="John Abbruzzi"
                     />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="0094 234 2345 890" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/presence_audio_away" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lincon Burrows" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="0094 342 5567 216" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>



        <include layout = "@layout/activity_drop_down_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

There is an issue with the `include` layout. Whenever the user touch the search `EditText` and open the Soft Keyboard, the `include` layout comes on top of the keyboard, just like the following (see the bar on top of the keyboard with "^^^" text.) I have highlighted it in red colour

[image]

Following is the code of this `include` layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:alpha="0.7">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slideButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="^^^"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_gray" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_add_inquiry"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/add_inquiry" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onMenuItemClicked" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_add_event"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/add_event" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_additional_info"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/additional_info"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_add_to_contacts"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/add_to_contacts" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I do not want this `include` layout to come on top of te keyboard when it is Open. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` to manifest - to the corresponding activity:

```
  <activity android:name="MyActivity"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
    ...
  </activity>
```

Comment: I can't. I already added 'android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"'. So I can't put 2 codes of the same

Comment: Done. I adeed that part by adding "|". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. Working. I will accept this as the answer after the 'answer acceptence restriction time' is passed